Safari not recognizing table thead's height with tailwind css
I created Table with react-table package but I have one problem, connected with safari height recognizing. it shows that safari reads the height in inspect, but it does not react to it. when I enlarge it for example to 100px, it does not give any reaction.
how to fix ?
<thead className="bg-[#E5EDFF] h-[43px] border-b-[1px] border-b-[D2DFFF]">
It works pretty fine in google chrome, microsoft edge but safari gives some problems. any solutions for this ?
I tried to change thead to div, but it collapsed my full table, and I expect it to have 43 height in safari.

Do you havae a typo? Should D2DFFF be #D2DFFF? Also, using your browser devtools inspect facility, could you find the exact CSS that is being applied and show us?

use
<thead className="bg-[#E5EDFF] min-h-[43px] border-b-[1px] border-b-[D2DFFF] table-header-group">

instead of
<thead className="bg-[#E5EDFF] h-[43px] border-b-[1px] border-b-[D2DFFF]">

also make sure your table tag should look like this
<table className="table-fixed w-full">

if it is still not working then add this style to global css file
thead {
  display: table-header-group;
  height: 43px
}

or you can add Safari specific style
@supports (-webkit-appearance: none) {
  thead {
    height: 43px
  }
}

